# What is the disadvantage of using Django's fastcgi server

Tags: django, deployment, fastcgi, gunicorn

I'm using `nginx + fastcgi`( manage.py runfcgi ...) on production for some of my Django projects. A lot of people suggests to use `nginx + gunicorn`. What is advantage of using **gunicorn** instead of using Django's `fastcgi` server?

Comment: FastCGI Deprecated since version 1.7: FastCGI support is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9., so i suggest go for uWSGI.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm just tell why you need to use WSGI-like servers :) but if you feel comfortable with using fcgi - just use it

Short answer: WSGI (as protocol) is cool because [its native](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/)

Or if "You need to go deeper"(c)

Next question "FastCGI vs WSGI-like servers?"

Some answers here:

- [Differences and uses between WSGI, CGI, FastCGI, and mod_python in regards to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937224/differences-and-uses-between-wsgi-cgi-fastcgi-and-mod-python-in-regards-to-py)
- [What's the difference between scgi and wsgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257481/whats-the-difference-between-scgi-and-wsgi)
- [Is there a speed difference between WSGI and FCGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747266/is-there-a-speed-difference-between-wsgi-and-fcgi)
- [How Python web frameworks, WSGI and CGI fit together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219110/how-python-web-frameworks-wsgi-and-cgi-fit-together)

About gunicorn, uWSGI and cherokee, nginx. Dont mix them!

nginx is web-server which can handle http requests and can send it to WSGI backend. ( But first of all it extremly fast for static content handling. )
And WSGI backend handle you django application.

About cherokee, I think it handle the same tasks as nginx but I'm not work with it.

And gunicorn, uWSGI are WSGI backend which run threads with django app and do [many other tasks](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/#CurrentCoreFeatures)

And hmmm, [gunicorn say](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/PHILOSOPHY.html) that

> Being a server that only runs on Unix-like platforms, unicorn is strongly tied to the Unix philosophy of doing one thing and (hopefully) doing it well. Despite using HTTP, unicorn is strictly a backend application server for running Rack-based **Ruby applications**.

I practice for my django apps nginx (latest stable from nginx.org repos)+uWSGI (from Debian stables) - works perfectly :)

---

edited 18.05.2012

Link to 2010 topic with comparing [fcgi gunicorn uWSGI](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/fcgi-vs-gunicorn-vs-uwsgi/)

> fcgi (threaded)              640 r/s
>
> fcgi (prefork 4 processors)  240 r/s (*)
>
> gunicorn (2 workers)         1100 r/s
>
> gunicorn (5 workers)         1300 r/s
>
> gunicorn (10 workers)        1200 r/s (?!?)
>
> uwsgi (2 workers)            1800 r/s
>
> uwsgi (5 workers)            2100 r/s
>
> uwsgi (10 workers)           2300 r/s
>
> (* this made my computer exceptionally sluggish as CPU when through the roof)

Comment: "FastCGI vs. WSGI" is the wrong question. FastCGI is a network protocol and WSGI is a Python calling convention. [flup](http://trac.saddi.com/flup) has a FastCGI-to-WSGI gateway. Django’s `runfcgi` command is actually based on flup, and thus uses WSGI.
A better question is flup vs. uwsgi or flup vs. gunicorn.

Comment: You are right about "FastCGI vs. WSGI". Change in topic to WSGI-like. And I think battle `flup vs. uwsgi vs. gunicorn` win uWSGI. I'll try to provide some proofs soon.

Comment: Well, who "wins" depends on what’s your criteria. I’m hosting a dozen sites with low traffic, so ease of maintenance and memory usage are more important *for me* than raw performance (which is dominated by database queries anyway.) uwsgi is not packaged in debian squeeze (the current stable), while flup and gunicorn are.

Comment: just a heads up: implying that gunicorn is not a good solution for Django because it is intended to be used with Ruby is flat out wrong. The poster got gunicorn and unicorn mixed up - the quote is taken from unicorn (a Ruby http server), not gunicorn.

Answer (score 4):

As b1- says, WSGI is native (take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747266/is-there-a-speed-difference-between-wsgi-and-fcgi)).

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591715/deploying-django-fastcgi-apache-mod-wsgi-uwsgi-gunicorn) has a similar question.

From my personal point of view, some time ago i've been using [Nginx + uwsg in vhost mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081462/problem-with-nginx-uwsgi-in-vhost-mode-running-django-app) to run various project on my server.

Comment: ...and uWSGI has zerg mode ^_^